# $? in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to figure out what this means/how `$?` gets populated in linux, I tried doing a search but if someone could clarify that would be great:

```
exitstat=$?

if [ $exitstat -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo -e "Could Not Extract"
    echo -e "Aborting Script `date`"
    exit $exitstat
fi
```

The code above that is:

```
_xfile << %%  2> /files/thefile-7000.log |  _afile -x -r 10 2> /files/thefile-7000.log > /files/thefile.7000
OperatorHigh = $finalnumber
%%
```

Comment: Shows the exit status (0 if success, positive int up to 127 if fail) of the last command

Comment: Ok so the command above it, i see.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want multiple independent redirections writing to the same file unless doing so in append mode. Lots of room for unintended consequences there. Better to open an FD just once and reuse the descriptor in multiple places than to open it several times independently.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not my script, but thanks we are having issues with random errors (which is why I was looking into it). Could you show me an example?  Thanks!

Comment: `exec 2>/files/thefile-7000.log` just once, at the top of your script, will redirect stderr for the whole script. By contrast, `exec 3>/files/thefile-7000.log` will redirect file descriptor *3* for the whole script, then you can use `exec 2>&3` anywhere you want stderr to go to that location, without worrying about the different handles stomping on each other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks

Comment: err, or just `2>&3` anywhere you want to redirect stderr, don't want the `exec` unless your goal is to redirect for the shell itself (and thus all future commands as well) rather than the command it's presently invoking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$?` expands to the exit status of the most recent foreground command.

Since your prior command is a pipeline, the exit status is that of the last command in the pipeline -- in this case, `_afile` -- **unless** the `pipefail` shell option is set, in which case failures elsewhere in the pipeline can also make exit status nonzero.